# Responsive float issue

Tags: css, responsive-design, css-float

I'm developing a responsive website where I go from three, two and lastly to one column per row.

The problem I have is that the text length varies between the columns which means that some columns will not fit and therefore they are getting pushed down. Note that the columns are fluid so the text becomes longer and shorter depending on the screen size.

Which is the most effective way to fix this?

Comment: can you make a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for it? Or show us some code?

Comment: You need to change the width % of the columns based on screen size using media queries.

Comment: This is an example on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pauwner/NP6pu/). Adding a clear class ain't ideal because of different number of columns per row depending on screen size. Another option is to use the min-height by making sure that all columns are as high as the highest. The problem is that the height is constantly changing depending on the screen size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure, if this it what you want, but take a look http://jsfiddle.net/H5E35/1/ ^^

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-size: 0px; // fix, so there is no gap between the elements
    vertical-align:top;
}

.col {
    vertical-align:top;
    font-size: 14px;
    width: 33.33%; // is more precise than 33
    background-color: green;
    display: inline-block;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
    .col {
        width: 50%;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    .col {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```